# makefile: multiple automatic variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have the following:

```
$: make foo-bar

// makefile contents
.PHONY foo-

foo-%:
    echo $*
```

And I would like increased flexibility:

```
# either: 

$: make foo-bar:foobar

# or: 

$: make foo-bar-foobar

// makefile contents, pseudocode

.PHONY foo- foo-?-?

foo-%:
    echo $*

foo-%1-%2:
    echo $*1 $*2
```

With the caveat that I have seen large, automatically generated makefiles that have successfully implemented sophisticated interfaces such as:

```
make foo:bar:baz
```

Ideally, it would be possible to implement the logical notation:

```
make foo::bar:baz

# but I understand that this may be reaching.
```

---

Is any of this possible with modern gnu make? I am not worried about older versions.  And the advantage comes from conciseness and cleanliness, as verses some verbose workaround.

Comment: Make doesn't support two "percent" signs in a rule. Or, more precisely, the second one will be treated as a literal char. But you can generate rules using built-in substitutions and stuff, instead of external generators. This is relatively terse, but harder to debug.

Comment: @Matt suppose I `make foo-bar-baz` with a double rule: `foo-%` and `bar-%`, calling `bar-%` from within `foo-%`

Comment: That would require an explicit rule for each possible second segment (i.e you would need `bar-%:`, `bar1-%:`, `bar2-%:`, which could get pretty ugly pretty fast...  (Also, it would stop working if you tried `foo-foo-bar` for example...)

Comment: Note your `.PHONY` rules here are useless. .PHONY only accepts literal targets, it doesn't accept patterns.  You're declaring the literal filename `foo-%` including the `%` to be phony.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks, corrected.  Hacking it at the moment for use in an alternative case to shield my brain from some java workflow jargon. Never had any formal instruction on its usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a finite number of possibilities for each segment, one option is if you do something like:

```
 targs := $(foreach v1,foo foo1 foo2,\
        $(foreach v2,bar bar1 bar2,\
          $(foreach v3,foobar1 foobar2 foobar3, \
            $(v1)-$(v2)-$(v3))))

$(targs) :
    @IFS=- read v1 v2 v3 <<< $@; \
    echo $$v1 $$v2 $$v3
```

otherwise, if the first segment is always `foo-` then you could do:

```
 foo-% :
       IFS=- read v1 v2 v3 <<< $@; \
       echo $$v1 $$v2 $$v3
```

Outside of that, you would likely need to create a script to break the target into parts manually, and potentially invoke a submake if you wanted to use those parts as seperate targets.

Comment: Thanks man, this is deep enough voodoo to mess around with for a while.